# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, does $q^k < n$ imply that $\sigma(q^k) < n$?

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Here is the:

**PROBLEM**

> If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, does $q^k < n$ imply that $\sigma(q^k) < n$?

$\sigma(x)$ is the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  The special prime $q$ satisfies $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

From the divisibility constraint $\gcd(q,n)=1$, we immediately get $q^k \neq n$.  Suppose now that we have $q^k < n$.  Is it then possible to obtain $\sigma(q^k) < n$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Assume that $q^k < n$.  This is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{q^k}$$
which in turn is equivalent to
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k}.$$
But from the formula for the divisor sum $\sigma$, we get (since $q$ is prime)
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k} = \frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q^k (q - 1)} < \frac{q^{k+1}}{q^k (q - 1)} = \frac{q}{q - 1} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{q}}.$$
Since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then we have $q \geq 5$, which is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{1}{5} \iff 1 - \frac{1}{q} \geq \frac{4}{5} \iff \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{q}} \leq \frac{5}{4}.$$

Hence, we conclude that:

> If $q^k < n$, then $\sigma(q^k) < \dfrac{5n}{4}$.

**QUESTIONS**

> **(1)** Will it be possible to tweak this argument to produce an unconditional proof for $\sigma(q^k) < n$?

> **(2)** If an unconditional proof for $\sigma(q^k) < n$ is not possible, under what conditions can it be proved?

Comment: If I understand your questions correctly, I think that the answer to **(1)** is no. It seems to me that you are basically trying to prove that $\bigg(\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} <\bigg) \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k}\le 1$, but this is impossible since $\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k}\gt 1$ always holds. (If I'm not mistaken, I think that this does not mean that an unconditional proof for $\sigma(q^k)<n$ is not possible.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @mathlove!  But it certainly can happen that
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < 1 < \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k},$$
does it not?

Comment: I'm answering to the question **(1)** saying "Will it be possible to **tweak this argument** to produce an unconditional proof for $\sigma(q^k) < n$?". What my first comment meant was that one needs a different approach. That's why I wrote "I think that this does not mean that an unconditional proof for $\sigma(q^k)<n$ is not possible". I'm not saying anything to a question "Is it possible to produce an unconditional proof for $\sigma(q^k) < n$?" which seems what you meant by **(1)**.

Comment: Oops sorry @mathlove, I misread your comment.

Comment: How about the following approach, @mathlove?  Although admittedly, I did not get anything much from this:

$$q^k < n \iff q^{k+1} < nq \iff q^{k+1} - 1 < nq - 1 \iff \sigma(q^k)=\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q-1} < \frac{nq - 1}{q - 1} \iff \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \frac{nq - 1}{n(q - 1)}$$

Comment: I don't know how to prove $n\gt \sigma(q^k)$ from it, but it is better than $\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n}\lt \frac 54$ which is what you already have since $\frac{nq-1}{n(q-1)}\lt \frac 54$ always holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

Under the assumption $q^k < n$, it *is possible* to prove $\sigma(q^k) < n$ when $k=1$.

To see why, assume that $q = q^k < n$.  Assume to the contrary that $n < \sigma(q^k) = \sigma(q) = q+1$.  Together, the two inequalities yield
$$q < n < q+1,$$
contradicting the fact that $n$ is an integer.  This concludes the proof.

Comment: Indeed, Patrick A. Brown proved in a 2016 preprint that $k=1 \implies q<n$. Together with a 2012 result of Dris published in JIS ($n<q \implies k=1$), this implies $q<n$. It remains to prove the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture that $k=1$, in order to prove $q^k < n$.